# Detecting if a program is installed and where using cmd.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell, cmd

Windows has the program start.exe which somehow knows how to open programs by their lay-name like "firefox"

Typing `start firefox` into cmd.exe opens firefox assuming its installed.
Is there a similar command to start that will return the file path rather than starting the application?

Also open to any similar but proper solution

UPDATE:
Other answers suggest using `where` command, and this works for programs like ping which are in the system directories, but does not find firefox like `start` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this registry key.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

In it you will find something similar to this for firefox.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox"
```

and here is a bit that reads the value from Powershell.  Same thing can be done from batch file with reg.exe.

```
$Firepath = get-item -path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe'
$Firepath.GetValue('')
```

Comment: I searched for awhile and never found these keys! Thank you so much.  This contains exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The mentioned reg.exe command is `reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe" /v Path` and requires additional output parsing.

Answer (score 0):

wmic product get name,version /format:csv > C:\testappu\Computername%.csv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).